# How to access dataframe column by variable / string

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm struggling to achieve something supposedly simple. I have dataframe `df` with columns `a` and `b`. If I call `df$a`, `df$"a"` `` df$`a` ``, it works. So I'm thiking I can assign a variable a string, and then use that. But if I do and try to get the column with it, I get `Unknown or uninitialised column`.

```
df = data.frame(a=(1:3), b=c("a", "b", "c"))
df$a # works
df$`a` # works
df$"a" # works

x <- "a"
df$x # error
```

How to solve this?

Comment: use `df[,x]` instead

Comment: as @AdamQuek indicates; or `df[[x]]`

Comment: Just to clarify the above two comments, `df[,x] or df[x]` returns a **single column data frame** whereas `df[[x]] or df$a` returns a **vector**

Comment: @Sotos - You may have forgotten that `df[, x]` will return a vector,  `df[, x, drop = FALSE]` is needed to return a single column data frame.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento That's correct and interesting. I had it `as_tibble()` and that returns a data frame without the `drop` argument. Data frames on the other hand return a vector.